# Turn on bluetooth on login screen

Tags: linux, arch-linux, login, daemon, bluetooth

Is it possible to have bluetooth turned on and use a bluetooth keyboard when at the login screen? So far I only managed to start the bluetooth daemon when logged in. I added it to systemd with `systemctl enable bluetooth`, so it starts when I am in my user, although it is turned off by default which I'd like to fix as well.

I installed the `bluez` and `bluez-utils` which provide the `bluetoothhctl` utility. Also I am using `blueman` as a front-end if that is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most of the time I didn't read the Arch Wiki carefully enough. There is a section on how to have the device active after booting.

You need to set a udev rule and to do so create `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` with the following code

```
# Set bluetooth power up
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 up"
```

That's it... it should now work, even without X running.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it worked on 18.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: This is deprecated, http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-35/
Look at my answer for a valid method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 10):

By default, the Bluetooth adapter does not power on after a reboot.

So, if you want to **auto power-on after boot** you need to add the line `AutoEnable=true` in the configuration file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` at the bottom in the `[Policy]` section:

```
/etc/bluetooth/main.conf
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Policy]
AutoEnable=true
```

Note: The former method by using hciconfig hci0 up is deprecated.

Source: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Auto_power-on_after_boot)

Comment: In my case, I need to set the `DiscoverableTimeout=0` under `[General]` section as well

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed using `systemd`:

1. Let `bluetooth.service` be required by `multi-user.target`. I used a `systemd` drop-in directory to implement it:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d/multi-user.conf << EOF
[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target multi-user.target
EOF
systemctl enable bluetooth.service
```

2. Install the `bluez-auto-enable-devices` package to generate the required `AutoEnable=true` configuration in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

```
zypper in -y bluez-auto-enable-devices
```

After reboot, my bluetooth keyboard and mouse works on the login screen as well. No need to open the laptop lid and use the laptop's keyboard for login.

Answer (score -1):

In latest kernel I had to use:

```
# Set bluetooth power up
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/bin/bluetoothctl --agent menu power on"
```